# Image centering with pandoc markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I need to create documents periodically for Word-using administrators. How can I centre an image using pandoc markdown? I see mention of div blocks, but I have no idea what they are.

```
![](myimage.png){.center}
```

With image code such as that above, and a command line such as:

```
pandoc -s test.md -o test.docx
```

or

```
pandoc -s test.md -o test.pdf
```

I always end up with left-aligned images in my document.

Answer (score 6):

For PDF output, using the implicit_figure option will automatically center image on page and allow you to display an title for images.

In the .md document:

```
![This is an image](path/to/image.png)
```

Run the following command to generate PDF from you .md

```
pandoc ./README.md \
  -o ./README.pdf \
  -f markdown+implicit_figures
```

Comment: It seems it is the caption that is crucial here - not the `implicit_figures` extension. Also, this only works when creating pdf documents (not docx).

Comment: implicit_figures is on by default in the `markdown` input format. It only applies when the caption is there though. It also doesn't really answer the question, which doesn't want any caption but still centering.

Comment: The caption will work even if it's empty like ```![\ ](image_file.jpg)```

Comment: The caption will work even if it's empty like `![\ ](image_file.jpg)`, but "Figure 1." will still be printed

Comment: `\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}` to remove the "Figure: " prefix in the caption

Answer (score 3):

This has been bugging me since forever; but if you use the markdown -> pandoc -> Latex -> PDF route, this should work:

````
```{=latex}
\begin{center}
```

![](folder/img.png){ height=30% } 

```{=latex}
\end{center}
```
````

Note that without the `{=latex}` wrapper (raw attribute), the above Latex commands will get interpreted as text in the final PDF. References:

[Allow to center images without caption in Beamer · Issue #3995 · jgm/pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3995)

> Pandoc doesn't aim to be a layout engine, see http://pandoc.org/CONTRIBUTING.html#out-of-scope
>
> However, you can change your LaTeX template or even write raw TeX (for both, see the MANUAL).

[Raw LaTeX gets interpreted as text in a markdown document. · Issue #4646 · jgm/pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4646)

> For such complicated raw TeX you should probably use http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_attribute

Answer (score 2):

If you are using something such as [pandoc-template](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template) that uses latex underneath, you can insert latex instructions, and they will be interprated.

```latex
\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[]{./images/my_image.png}
\end{center}
```

Comment: OP never said they were using latex

Comment: OP did mention compiling to pdf, however, and this answer did say "if . . . using . . . latex", which is my use case. This is the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the image to render as a figure, you can add styling to make it centered.
There are two ways to make the image render as a figure:

1. Give it a caption:

   `![Caption](folder/img.png){ style="width: 70%; margin: auto;" }`
2. For some reason, if you don't provide a caption, Pandoc won't create a figure. In that case you can do it manually:

   `<figure>![](folder/img.png){ style="width: 70%; margin: auto;" }</figure>`

Comment: I find only the first works, and only for pdf documents.